# Basic Shape class and Circle Class: compiling error

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism

I have this homework assignment to do and I did most of the code, but I have a remaining compiling error in `main()`, that I do not understand.

Here's the assignment:

> 1. Define an abstract base class called BasicShape. The BasicShape class should have the following members (...)
> 2. Define a class named Circle. It should be derived from the BasicShape class.
>        It should have the following members:
>
>    a)   Private Member Variable: radius (a double used to hold the circle’s
>      radius)
>
>    b)   Constructor and Public Member Functions:
>
>    - Circle(double a, string
>        n, double r): constructor that should call the base class constructor
>        to initialize the member area with a and name with n. The constructor
>        will also set the value of member radius with r
>    - calcArea():
>        Overridden function (...)
>    - print(): Overridden function (...)
> 3. After you have created these classes, create a test program 
>      (...)

And here's my code:

**Basic Shape.h**

```
#ifndef BASICSHAPE_H
#define BASICSHAPE_H
#include <string>
class basicShape
{
public:
    basicShape(const std::string &, double &);
    double getArea() const;
    virtual double calcArea() const = 0;
    virtual void print()const;
    std::string getname()const;
protected:
    const double area;
private:
    const std::string name;
};

#endif
```

**Circle.h**

```
#ifndef CIRCLE_H
#define CIRCLE_H
#include <string>
#include "Basic Shape.h"
using namespace std;
class Circle : public basicShape
{
public:
    Circle(const string & n, double & a, double & r);
    virtual double calcArea() const override;
    virtual void print() const override;
private:
    double radius;
};
#endif
```

**Circle.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Circle.h"
#include<string>
using namespace std;

Circle::Circle(const string &n, double &a,  double &r)
:basicShape(n,a)
{
    radius = r;
    calcArea();
}
double Circle::calcArea() const 
{
    double area;
    area = 3.14159*radius*radius;
    return area;
   }
double basicShape::getArea() const
{
   return area;
}
void Circle::print() const
{
   cout << "radius:" << radius;
   basicShape::print();
   basicShape::getname();
}
```

**Test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Basic Shape.h"
#include "Circle.h"
#include <string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
void poly(const basicShape * const);

int main()
{ 
    Circle circle("Round",0.0,10.0);
    vector< basicShape * > shapes(1);
    for (const basicShape *basicshapePtr : shapes)
         poly(basicshapePtr);
}
void poly(const basicShape * const baseClassPtr)
{
   baseClassPtr->calcArea();
   baseClassPtr->print();
}
```

Here is the compiling error I get in main:

```
 "Circle::Circle(Circle Assignment 3 &&)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'double' to 'double &'
```

Comment: Saying "I have an error" and then blasting us with a wall of text which contains most everything except the error itself is a recipe for a bad time.

Comment: ***Here's what the assignment saids:*** That is not really what this site is about. We are not here to do your homework or play a game of guess what is wrong with this code. Tell us exactly what problem you are having with your code. If there was an error message put the exact text of the error message in the question. Do not take a screenshot of the error text. Instead copy the text from your IDE. If this is a compiler error and this is Visual Studio copy the text from the Output tab not the errors tab.

Comment: Forgot to say what the error is, the error is in the part in int main() where I'm initializing the object circle. For some reason, it's always the first argument. I would switch it around and it's always the first argument.

Comment: You also should have split the code into each file instead of posting it all in 1 code section.

Comment: Sorry about that guys, I rarely ask questions here. There's actually two errors, the first one is "no instance of constructor "Circle::Circle" matches the argument list" and the other one is "Circle::Circle(Circle Assignment 3 &&)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'double' to 'double &'

Comment: `Circle::Circle(const string &n, double &a,  double &r)` probably should be `Circle::Circle(string n, double a,  double r)`

Comment: That gave me more errors.....

Comment: Then you need to be specific of the more errors. Also I meant that you had to make the changes to the header and the cpp file.

Comment: Your basicShape() constructor is similarly wrong. You again pass your doubles to your constructors by value.

Comment: Ok that error got away now, but now when I compile it, I think the vectors are giving me problems.

Comment: It's giving visual studio a problem, it's giving an error box saying "A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available."

Comment: You set the vector to contain 1 pointer to a shape but did not allocate the shape.

Comment: @JeffreyMeza why don't you also add the tag `Assigment` or `Homework`?

Answer (score 0):

**The problem**

You try to construct your new circle here:

```
Circle circle("Round",0.0,10.0);
```

But your constructor has the following signature:

```
Circle(const string &n, double &a,  double &r)
```

For the second and third arguments you use references to double values.  Passing by reference like this means that you could change the value that is referenced. Unfortunately, you pass constant literals. This is not allowed.

**The solution**

Either define your constructor by using const references:

```
Circle(const string &n, const double &a,  const double &r)
```

or, pass by value:

```
Circle(string n, double a,  double r)
```

Note that the second option seems preferred here.  And I'd even advise you to respect the signature given in the assignment, which would have avoided you those troubles.

*P.S.: For future questions, please reduce the question to the minimal elements required to reproduce the errors, instead of posting the full assignment and the full code, most of which being not relevant to the error*